# Application freezes in IOS 10

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer, ios10, xcode8

I have developed a application where it uses **GCD** timer and **Sqlite** database it works fine in IOS8 and IOS9 but it fails in IOS10 that it it does not crash but it freezes I am using Xcode 8.1.
The work flow of the application is when i click on the button timer will start running in background and keep on update the label as well as table list data and inserting the same data to the sqlite database.

Here my problem is when i keep on click the button to update the data it works fine until it insert the 50-60 records after it suddenly freezes and block the UI so to check that i have debug the code I came up with the assumption that it fails because it's blocking the thread but I did not find any solution to resolve it please help me out to resolve my problem thanks in advance.

[Here is the output from my pause:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgXDl.png)

[Error showing after pause and debug:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMmgG.png)

On click of button event I am trying to reload the table and displaying records in it as well as inserting the data to the sqlite database and I have a label which shows the timer data in it.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.lbltimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", Timeinterval];
    });
```

Below is my code how I am using GCD timer which runs continuously:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                                    self.aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(ShowTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];      
                                });
```

Comment: I can't say exactly but this must be because your async threads are not stopping and after adding 50 - 60 records, you have 50 - 60 background threads. That blocks the UI. I guess you are creating new threads every time but they are not finishing. I can say only this by looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start the timer on the main thread 
by triggering :

```
-(IBAction)clickEven:(id)sender{     

 self.aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1    
target:self selector:@selector(ShowTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 //Sqlite operation 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self.aTimer invalidate];
   });
});
}

-(void)ShowTime:(NSTimer*)timer {
 self.lbltimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", Timeinterval];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer..
  I have tried in that way also still it's the same and did not work as I expected. I do not know what exactly happened but i found my expected result by commenting on the dispatch queue while updating to the sqlite now it is working fine and not blocking the UI.